# Error in Install Package using composer in laravel

Tags: laravel, composer-php

Recently I had a problem with install package using composer in my laravel project
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kPwcU.png)

please Help me thanks

Comment: It is literally described in this error. Just read it carefully, and if you still have problem then explain with what part exactly.

Comment: yeah i see , but i dont know what should i do 
change guzzlehttp version or ... ??

Comment: Payping-php-client is using older version of guzzle than laravel, so you can ask author to support guzzle 7 or make fork yourself. You can also force it to install which is bad practice.

Comment: Please share more details, like the error message in text form and your attempts to resolve the error

Answer (score 1):

Either downgrade Laravel - or replace that outdated rubbish with a Laravel 8 version:

```
composer remove felotfeali/payping-php-client
composer require tdanandeh/payping
```

That repository seems abandoned: https://github.com/payping/payping-php-client/issues

I mean, actually **they** would have to provide packages for different Laravel versions.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it for you as another fork.

```
composer remove felotfeali/payping-client
composer require hmdshariati/payping-client
```

tell me if it worked. I'll fix any problem for you in my package. according to the stats of felotfeali he developed his last commit 3 years ago and I guess he will not continue.